# Find the longest subsequence with minimum sum of contiguous nodes in a circular linked list with at least K elements?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

The problem is I have a circular linked list, for example:
-12->-55->47->-33->-25->14
I want to return a sub sequence of this linked list with at least 4 elements(the answer is -33->-25->14->-12->-55)

I have done much research on the internet but I don't see anything about this problem. I solve it at the complexity O(n^2) but my professor want it at O(n).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since the linked list is circular, what if the total sum of elements in a single cycle is negative? There wouldn't be a minimum sum in such a case since adding a new cycle would give a smaller sum each time.

Comment: Elements in the sub sequence must be unique